# lejos noclassdeffounderror lejos/pc/comm/NXTComm

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

First I created a Java App to test my code to contact the NXT Brick using Bluetooth. Once this worked I created a Webservice instead which should connect to the NXT Brick through Bluetooth.

This is where the problems start. My Webservice works fine, I can see the services and I can invoke them.
One service uses NXTComm, which is in the Lejos PC Libraries (lejos.pc.comm.NXTComm). I've added these libraries to the project and I've added "import lejos.pc.comm.*;" at the top of the class but I still get the following error.

```
[ERROR] lejos/pc/comm/NXTComm
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lejos/pc/comm/NXTComm
at mindstorms.Connector.getBots(Connector.java:111)
at mindstorms.MindstormService.getBots(MindstormService.java:30)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lejos.pc.comm.NXTComm
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
... 31 more
```

Why can't the services get to these libraries and what should I do to fix this?

Comment: verify if the class **lejos.pc.comm.NXTComm** available in the classpath when running?

Comment: This is what I get if I output 
System.out.println("classpath=" + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

classpath=D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar

So no it's not in there but why isn't there more in there? You sure it should be in there?

Answer (score 0):

So what have you done in order to add the leJOS libraries to your web application? Why would you expect, that they are in the classpath?

It might work, if you but the JAR files from the folder lib/pc in your leJOS distribuion into the WEB-INF/lib folder of your web application. Alternatively, there is a directory for libraries that all web application can access. It must be located somewhere where Tomcat is located.

BTW: The system property java.class.path does not really return the paths that are searched for classes. If one is using classloaders (which tomcat does), the paths they search are not present in java.class.path.